# C++ editing delete function of a class

Tags: c++

In my program, the function `void UnsortedType::DeleteItem(ItemType item)` deletes the user specified item, however it crashes if the user specified item doesn't exist.

```
void UnsortedType::DeleteItem(ItemType item)
// Pre:  item's key has been initialized.
//       An element in the list has a key that matches item's.
// Post: No element in the list has a key that matches item's.
{
    int location = 0;
    while (item.ComparedTo(info[location]) != EQUAL)
        location++;
    info[location] = info[length - 1];
    length--;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be lacking a test to ensure `location` does not go out of bounds when the item is not found. Somewhere you should have a container size you can compare against.

Comment: You do not appear to be checking if `location` is within the valid bounds of whatever container `info` is.  Your loop will never terminate if the item is not found.  You're also assuming that it _IS_ found later when you make changes.

Comment: It is possible to suggest a solution to you based on inferring the underlying types (_i.e._ educated guess), but it's unclear whether your `UnsortedType` can contain _multiple_ entries with the same key.  Lacking such information makes it difficult to suggest the most appropriate solution.

Comment: UnsortedType can contain multiple entries

Comment: What do you want your code to do if the specified item does not exist? Is there any code in your function to tell the computer to do that?

Comment: If the specified item doesn't exist I want the function to just exist.

Comment: @ronnie That is a valid option. Where in your function do you tell the computer that that is what you want? (Keep in mind that a computer cannot read your mind to figure out what you want it to do. You must give it instructions covering all cases.)